# Change form submit based on form heading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the same form for creating new records and editing an existing record. How can I specify which controller to call based on whether the form is submitting a new record or editing an existing record.

For example, in the code below, how do I change what controller gets called by f.submit based on whether the form is editing an existing record or submitting a new record?

```
<%= form_for :protocol, url: protocols_path, :html => {:class => 'form', :id => 'new-protocol'} do |f| %>
  <h1>Create New Protocol</h1>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'name'%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'button' %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, based on the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style), if you do:

```
<%= form_for @protocol :html => {:class => 'form', :id => 'new-protocol'} do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then, depending on whether `@protocol` is a new record or an existing record, the form will automatically submit to the correct action. (The problem that arises from using a symbol, e.g., `:protocol`, is that `form_for` can't tell if you're doing a create or update.)

Now, you'll have to do some fussing. Because you have `:id => 'new-protocol'` and `Create New Protocol` which you will want to switch depending on whether you're doing a create or an update.

Answer (score 1):

By default [form_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) will generate the form action automatically unless you specify the url, http verb, etc... it decides between `create` and `update` checking if it's a persisted object or not, in other words checking if the object has an `id`.

Ideally you should use the following:

```
<%= form_for @protocol do |f| %>
  <h1>Create New Protocol</h1>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'name'%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'button' %>
  </div>
```

In this way:

```
@protocol = Protocol.new #=> the form action will point to create action
@protocol = Protocol.find(params[:id]) #=> the form action will point to update action
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your thorough answer! I have to give jvillian the check since he responded first with a similar answer.